# can't get echo response from ws://echo.websocket.org in my websocket client

Tags: java, websocket

I'm trying to implement a simple websocket client in java using the javax websocket library, here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.websocket.*;

@ClientEndpoint
public class Client {

    Session session;

    private final static String url = "ws://echo.websocket.org";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        System.out.println("connecting...");
        container.connectToServer(Client.class,
                URI.create(url));
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void newMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    @OnOpen
    public void newConnection(Session session) throws IOException {
        this.session = session;
        System.out.println("The connection has been started");
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("hello");

    }
    @OnClose
    public void disconnection() {
        System.out.println("The connection has been ended");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the @OnOpen annotation i try to send the "Hello" string message and on the @OnMessage i just want print the message in the console.

I can run the code without errors, but i just got the "connecting..." print so can anyone explain what is wrong with the code?

Note:  i added the org.glassfish.tyrus libraries that's needed to work with the javax.websocket to the referenced libraries as well

I'm newbie in Java so sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is exiting immediately after calling `container.connectToServer(...)` so your `newConnection(...)` and `newMessage(...)` functions never get a chance to run. You need to keep your program running after the call to `container.connectToServer(...)`. You can do this by, for example, adding the following code after the `container.connectToServer(...)` line which will cause the program to wait for the ENTER key to be pressed:

```
        System.out.println("Press ENTER key to exit.");
        System.in.read();
```

After making that change, your program worked correctly on my computer and displayed the "The connection has been started" and "hello" messages.